# In Typescript, how to use a function before it's declared?

Tags: typescript

I want to declare a function, pass it as a handler, then define it afterward, my code is like this:

```
type authenticateHandler = (req: Restify.Request, res: Restify.Response) => any;
server.post("/authentication", authenticateHandler);
server.post("/v1/authentication", authenticateHandler);

const authenticateHandler: authenticateHandler = (req: Restify.Request, res: Restify.Response) => { ... };
```

I am getting this error when passing the function on line 2, what am I doing wrong?

> TS2448: Block-scoped variable 'authenticateHandler' used before its
>   declaration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either declare your constant function before it's used (as the warning suggests).

```
type AuthenticateHandler = (req: Restify.Request, res: Restify.Response) => any;

const authenticateHandler: AuthenticateHandler = (req: Restify.Request, res: Restify.Response) => { ... };

server.post("/authentication", authenticateHandler);
server.post("/v1/authentication", authenticateHandler);
```

Or define it as a function:

```
function authenticateHandler(req: Restify.Request, res: Restify.Response) => { ... };
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll go with a function because it's too long